# How to get probability with standard deviation, mean, and x?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

For some reason, I can’t seem to get this. I’ve used normalpdf and it comes up as a number that doesn’t make sense. The exact question is as follows:

The tread life of a particular brand of tire is a random variable best described by a normal distribution with a mean of 90,000 miles and a standard deviation of 6,000 miles. If we select a tire of this brand at random, what is the probability that the tire treat is worn out before 81,000 miles?

TLDR; Mean: 90,000 SD: 6,000 X: 81,000

Obviously change numbers up if you’d like, just looking for a good explanation of how to solve this sort of problem using a TI83.

Comment: +1 for your username

Comment: Take the difference between X and the mean. This gives you -9000. Divide by the standard deviation (6000) and you get $-1.5$. Look up in a tabel what the probability is of finding a result $-1.5$ or less.

Comment: As @M.Wind said, you want to standardize your distribution since the standard normal PDF and CDF are built into every graphing calculator and stats computer program